# An UFD order in a number field $K$ is necessarily $\mathscr{O}_K$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $A$ be an order of $K$. (That is, $A$ is a subring of $K$ which contains a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$.)

I want to prove that if $A$ is an unique factorization domain, then $A=\mathscr{O}_K$, the ring of integers of $K$.

By a standard Nakayama lemma argument, $A\subset\mathscr{O}_K$. However I don't know how to prove the other inclusion.

Comment: From my point of view, this is a corollary to the class number formula. But you might want a more direct proof...

Comment: Isn't a UFD integrally closed?

Comment: @WhatsUp, I would in fact prefer a more direct proof but I also don't see why it follows from the class number formula. (Does the class number formula generalizes to an arbitrary order?)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown you're absolutely right

Comment: Yes, the class number formula generalizes to arbitrary order. The $L$ function of an order is again a product of Euler factors, and the factors are the same as those of the maximal order, except for places dividing the conductor of the order. But of course the comment of @LordSharktheUnknown is much simpler than my roundabout argument (: